# Confirmation Modal Box Javascript in repeater control (findcontrol value getting wrong)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

```
    <body>
    
        <asp:Repeater ID="ProductView"  runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblOrderId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("OrderId") %>'  />
            <asp:LinkButton ID="bbtnDelete" CssClass="MordersButton"  runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false" Text='<%#Eval("PaymentStatus") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
            <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClick="DeleteRecord" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />    
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    
       
    <div id="dialog" style="display: none" align="center">
        Do you want to delete this record?
    </div>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("[id*=btnDelete]").removeAttr("onclick");
                $("#dialog").dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    autoOpen: false,
                    title: "Confirmation",
                    width: 350,
                    height: 160,
                    buttons: [
                    {
                        id: "Yes",
                        text: "Yes",
                            click: function () {
                               
                            $("[id*=btnDelete]").attr("rel", "delete");
                            $("[id*=btnDelete]").click();
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        id: "No",
                        text: "No",
                        click: function () {
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        }
                    }
                    ]
                });
                $("[id*=btnDelete]").click(function () {
                    if ($(this).attr("rel") != "delete") {
                        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        __doPostBack(this.name, '');
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>


 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            FlavorImage1Bind();
        }
    }
    protected void DeleteRecord(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RepeaterItem item = (sender as Button).Parent as RepeaterItem;
        int addressID = int.Parse((item.FindControl("lblOrderId") as Label).Text);
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Record Deleted.')", true);
    }
    private void FlavorImage1Bind()
    {

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DC_ManageOrders_Select", cn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Userid", "1");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FilterType", "3");
        SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DA.Fill(dt);
        // dt = sliderhelper.GetsliderImage();  
        ProductView.DataSource = dt;
        ProductView.DataBind();

    }
```

In the repeater control the orderid starts with 1080,
each control has a delete button, I clicked **orderid 2031** delete button and in the confirmation dialog box clicked yes.
Once clicked yes the deleted statement gets fired with the **orderid 1080** (actually I need to delete the orderid 2031)

Can someone please help to solve this?

Comment: It not clear why you doing a script inject in the delete button event? You can't confirm the button that way at all. The button is clicked, the page is fully posted back to server with valid sender.parent row. Code behind runs (button delete), then you inject script for a confirm, page travels back to client - you get a confirm dialog, and then you try and post back again? you LONG lost valid sender row. That program flow don't make sense - it can't work that way. See my post below. You click on the button - if you confirm, then button code will run with correct repeater item via btn.parent.

Comment: You have to dump that script inject - it causing another un-needed round trip,, but worse it means you lose which row of repeater was/is clicked this way. You don't need (nor want) the script inject for the confirm dialog - you don't need it if you follow my post below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, a few things.

First - your title? This is not JUST JavaScript.

You are using jQuery  - it should be tagged as such.

You are ALSO using jQuery.UI - it should be tagged as such.

and specific, out of hte jQuery.UI library, you are using the jQuery.UI dialog

Ok, now that been cleared up?

Next up?

I been coding for a long time. As a result, code WHEN possible should avoid things like document.onReady.

And we should try and avoid say having jQuery kind of, sort of, perhaps attach some click event to some button in some magic way. Now, don't get me wrong, document reedy, and magic jQuery selector functions that just run all by themselves like magic? Not too bad, but those that kind of pick out some control and THEN add some click stuff? I telling you now, REALLY make a effort to avoid such code.

This is also why I don't use the bootstrap dialogs. I think they look great, but you specify a bunch of classes - and some how, and somewhere by some feat of magic that makes a dialog pop up? (wow - just TRY to debug that kind of mess). I love bootstrap, but I quite much settled on the jQuery.UI dialog - and now I can write code that humans can read, but MORE important humans can also follow.

Now the key point here? (when we can avoid that fancy footwork, do so! - so this is not always! - but at least try!!!).

So, when building code? We place a button on the form. We have that button when clicked on run some code. And as noted, we should have a simple define of that function to run, and setup that information AT that location, and button in code. The result is code all of a sudden becomes enjoyable and fun again. It also means that you drop in a button, specify the functions to run (client side, and server side). And then you are quite much done.

Ok, next up:

in asp.net, when you use the onClientClick() event, you can VERY nice control if the server button code is to run, or not.

If the js function returns true, then your server side button click code will run (code behind).

And if the js function returns false, then your server side button click code will NOT run.

So, this means we simply want to specify a simple function for that button click, and ALSO a OnClientClick() event is also specified.

That function will return true/false, and that's quite much all we need to do.

Now, of course these days, jQuery.UI (and most new web widgets are async and they don't wait. However, that will not matter here.

so, say markup is this:

```
      <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" 
      OnClick="DeleteRecord" UseSubmitBehavior="false"
      OnClientClick = "return mydeleteprompt(this)" />
```

The above is ALL you need.

So, if the js function mydeleteprompt returns true, then the server side code you have will run

And VERY NICE that you using the btn.parent trick to get the repeater row - GREAT on your part!!! This is a great idea, and then you just drop in a button, use btn.Parent, and you can then just 100% ignore the repeater event model, and just code as if you dropped any old button on the form, and then attached a server side code behind event.

Love that trick/idea you using. Well done!!!

Ok, so, now lets build that js function - have it pop the jQuery dialog.

```
    <script>

        mydelpromptok = false
        function mydelprompt(btn) {

            if (mydelpromptok) {
                return true
            }

            var myDialog = $("#mydelprompt")
            myDialog.dialog({
                title: "Confirm delete",
                modal: true,
                width: "320px",
                resizable: false,
                appendTo: "form",
                autoOpen: false,
                buttons: {
                    ok: function () {
                        myDialog.dialog("close")
                        mydelpromptok = true
                        btn.click()
                    },
                    cancel: function () {
                        myDialog.dialog("close")
                    }
                }
            })
            myDialog.dialog('open')
            return false
        }
```

Note the "trick" here. Since jQuery.UI dialogs do NOT wait, then when you click on that standard asp.net button, the above dialog js routine runs. It will pop the dialog, and of course return false (so the server side code don't run/trigger).

Now, the dialog is displayed. Either you hit the ok button in dialog, or the cancel. Well, for cancel, we just close the dialog - nothing will happen.

But, if we hit Ok? Then we set our flag = true, and simply click the the SAME button again!!!! now the code will call this routine again, but this time, our flag = true, and thus the server side code will run.

So my "fake" coding standard is

function name = mycool()
and thus my flag for such functions will by mycoolok (I add the word "ok" to that function as a simple true/false flag.

But anyway, whatever you like - the trick here is that flag, and thus we save a hairy cat ball of code.

Enjoy:

Edit: ---------------------

Ok, so lets try this without a repeater. Lets do a proof of concept, and ensure that a simple button on a form, and a jQuery.UI dialog works.

So, we drop in a button, a cute "div" that will be the dialog, and then our js code to pop this dialog.

if we answer "ok", then the server side button code will run, if we don't ok  /confirm the dialog, we will NOT run the server side code.

So, we have this markup:

```
      <asp:Button ID="cmdDelete" runat="server" Height="30px" 
            OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Dialg test" Width="130px"
            OnClientClick="return mydialog(this)" ClientIDMode="Static"/>

        <div id="MyFunDialog" style="display:none">
            <h2>Really do the button click?</h2>
            <h3>Ok = run server buttion</h3>
            <h3>cancel - don't run button code</h3>
        </div>

        <script>

            myokok = false
            function mydialog(btn) {

                if (myokok) {
                    return true
                }
                // lets pop jquery.UI dialog
                var mydiv = $("#MyFunDialog")
                mydiv.dialog({
                    modal: true, appendTo : "form",
                    title: "Really do this?", closeText : "",
                    width: "400px",
                    buttons: {
                        ' ok ': function () {
                            mydiv.dialog('close')
                            myokok = true
                            btn.click() // click button again
                        },
                        ' cancel ': function () {
                            mydiv.dialog('close')
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false
            }

        </script>
```

And then we click on the button - lets wire up the server side (code behind) for this example. Our button code will thus be this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("<h2>This is the server button click</h2>");
    }
```

ok, now when we run this test simple example? you get this:

[image]

So, get the above working. Start  blank page - test that you have jQuery.UI installed and working.

once you get the above working, then you can use the approach in your application over and over - it is a GREAT design pattern.

Now ONLY when you are able to get the above working?

Ok, then, lets try this with a repeater, and see how it works much the same.

--------- repeater example ----------------

Now, as noted, if  you do this inside of a repeater ? It quite much the same.

With a repeater, we would have say this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div style="border-style:solid;color:black;width:300px;float:left">
        <div style="padding:5px;text-align:right">
            Hotel Name: <asp:TextBox ID="txtHotelName" runat="server" Text ='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>' Width="150px" />
            <br />                                                                                             
            First Name: <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirst" runat="server" Text ='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>'     Width="150px" />
            <br />                                                                                             
            Last Name: <asp:TextBox ID="txtLast" runat="server" Text ='<%# Eval("LastName") %>'        Width="150px" />
            <br />                                                                                             
            City: <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server" Text ='<%# Eval("City") %>'                 Width="150px" />
            <br />
            Active: <asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive" runat="server" Checked = '<%# Eval("Active") %>'/>

            <asp:HiddenField ID="PK" runat="server" Value = '<%# Eval("ID") %>'/>
            
            <asp:Button ID="cmdDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" style="margin-left:20px"
                  OnClientClick="return mydelprompt(this)"
                  OnClick="cmdDelete_Click"/>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div style="clear:both;height:4px"></div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</div>

    <div id="mycoolconfirmdialog" style="display:none">
        <h2>About to delete hotel</h2>
        <h3>This cannot be un-done</h3>
    </div>

      <script>

            myokok = false
            function mydelprompt(btn) {

                if (myokok) {
                    return true
                }
                // lets pop jquery.UI dialog
                var mydiv = $("#mycoolconfirmdialog")
                mydiv.dialog({
                    modal: true, appendTo : "form",
                    title: "Confirm delete of Hotel", closeText : "",
                    width: "400px",
                    buttons: {
                        ' ok ': function () {
                            mydiv.dialog('close')
                            myokok = true
                            btn.click() // click button again
                        },
                        ' cancel ': function () {
                            mydiv.dialog('close')
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false
            }

      </script>
```

And our code to load this looks like this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadData();
        }
    }
    public void LoadData()
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblHotels ORDER by HotelName",
                             new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4)))
        {
            cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
            Repeater1.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader();
            Repeater1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

And now lets add (fill out) the delete button code:

```
 protected void cmdDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // delete the row from database
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        RepeaterItem gRow = (RepeaterItem)btn.Parent;
        string PK = ((HiddenField)(gRow.FindControl("PK"))).Value;

        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM tblHotels WHERE ID = @ID",
            new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4)))
        {
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = PK;
            cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
            cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        LoadData();   // re-load repeater
    }
```

note very careful - we had to add a hidden field to hold the database PK "id". If you are concerned about security and don't want the PK id to be existing in the client browser side? Then dump the Repeater, and use a ListView. They work VERY similar - almost identical, but ListView (and grid views) have DataKeys option to hold the PK - and thus you do NOT have to put the PK in the markup, or expose it to client side.

Regardless, the results now look like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi Albert D.Kallal

Followed the same step as you mentioned above , but now the dialog box is not getting popup, can you please help on this , and thanks for your valuable time to give me an explantion

Comment: Ok, see my edit. I provide TWO working examples of how to do this. Try the first one - get it working. Then try the repeater example I have that works against the database.

Comment: Thanks a lot Albert D.Kallal, Its worked now , Once again thank you so much for your clear explanation and examples. Loved it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this.name in the line where you do __doPostBack to

```
__doPostBack(this.id, '');
```

You are sending the name of the button which would be the same for each of the items in the repeater, the id is unique. It may be the reason why the first item is the one that is deleted.